# How to ignore header on Signup Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I've created a header layout and currenlty it appears on every page of my website. I would like it to dissapear on the signup page (having multiple logo's looks poor).

Here's the content of my signup page */app/views/users/new.html.erb/*

```
<%= provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

      <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's the content of my */app/views/layouts/applications.html.erb*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>    
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
      <%= yield %>
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
      <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The `<%= render 'layouts/header' %>` is calling the header that I'd like to be ignored on my signup page.

I'm not sure if i need an `<% if .... %>` statement placed in the application.html.erb file or if i can somehow ignore the header in the new.html.erb file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine `content_for and a yield as described in the Ruby on Rails Guides on Nested Layouts. You would do something like this:`

In */app/views/layouts/applications.html.erb*

```
<head>
  <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
  <style type="text/css"><%= yield :stylesheets %></style>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>    
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header_id">
     <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <%= yield %>
    <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
    <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
  </div>
</body>
```

At the top of */app/views/users/new.html.erb*

```
<% content_for :stylesheets do %>
  #header_id { display: none }
<% end %>
```

Give the div containing your header a unique id and then replace #header_id above with that. It's not the most elegant solution, but it should work.

Comment: Ok after reading the link on Nested layouts, I was able to make it work. It originally wasn't working with your's because of the semi-colon after **none**. I'll update your comment. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Weird - I don't know why it would choke on the semicolon. I'll remove it from my answer to match the guide.